# Contextual Snippets in UltiSnips not working

Tags: vimscript-python, plugin-ultisnips, macos, plugin-vimtex

I have been using `vimtex` with `UltiSnips` for a while on Linux platform and it has been working just fine.

Recently, I switched to MacBook Air M1 for the same and installed the above mentioned plugins to work with `MacVim` using `vim-plug`. All `UltiSnips` snippets are working (expanding) except for those which use a `context` by which I mean that regular snippets expand as expected whereas the snippets involving a context do not expand. Also, I found out that if I comment out the **context "math()"** from snippets then they do expand. So basically the problem now is that the `context` environment is causing problems with snippet expansion. A sample for my snippets is provided below.

I suspect this is due to `MacVim` running on top of `Rosetta 2` but cannot be sure as nothing else has changed (maybe someone using same setup as me but on regular Intel chips can pitch in for more data).

Can someone help me figure out this thing?

Snippets :-

1. Regular snippets which do work :-

```
snippet pack "creates a usepackage command" bAm
\usepackage{${1:package_name}}
endsnippet
```

2. Context snippets which do not work (here the context is `math()`) :-

```
global !p
texMathZones = ['texMathZone' + x for x in ['A', 'AS', 'B', 'BS', 'C', 'CS',
'D', 'DS', 'E', 'ES', 'F', 'FS', 'G', 'GS', 'H', 'HS', 'I', 'IS', 'J', 'JS',
'K', 'KS', 'L', 'LS', 'DS', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AmsA', 'AmsB', 'AmsC',
'AmsD', 'AmsE', 'AmsF', 'AmsG', 'AmsAS', 'AmsBS', 'AmsCS', 'AmsDS', 'AmsES',
'AmsFS', 'AmsGS' ]]

texIgnoreMathZones = ['texMathText']

texMathZoneIds = vim.eval('map('+str(texMathZones)+", 'hlID(v:val)')")
texIgnoreMathZoneIds = vim.eval('map('+str(texIgnoreMathZones)+", 'hlID(v:val)')")

ignore = texIgnoreMathZoneIds[0]

def math():
    synstackids = vim.eval("synstack(line('.'), col('.') - (col('.')>=2 ? 1 : 0))")
    try:
        first = next(i for i in reversed(synstackids) if i in texIgnoreMathZoneIds or i in texMathZoneIds)
        return first != ignore
    except StopIteration:
        return False

keywords1 = { 'a' : '\\alpha',   'b' : '\\beta',   'g' : '\\gamma', 'd' : '\\delta', 'e' : '\\epsilon', 'z' : '\\zeta',   't' : '\\theta', 'i' : '\\iota', 'k' : '\\kappa',   'l' : '\\lambda', 's' : '\\sigma', 'o' : '\\omega',  'p' : '\\psi',  'A' : '\\Alpha',   'B' : '\\Beta',   'G' : '\\Gamma', 'D' : '\\Delta', 'E' : '\\Epsilon', 'Z' : '\\Zeta',   'T' : '\\Theta', 'I' : '\\Iota', 'K' : '\\Kappa', 'L' : '\\Lambda', 'S' : '\\Sigma', 'O' : '\\Omega', 'P' : '\\Psi' }

keywords2 = { 't' : '\\tau', 'p' : '\\pi', 'f' : '\\phi' , 'm' : '\\mu', 'n' : '\\nu', 'e' : '\\eta', 'T' : '\\Tau', 'P' : '\\Pi', 'F' : '\\Phi', 'M' : '\\Mu', 'N' : '\\Nu', 'E' : '\\Eta'}
endglobal

######################################################################

context "math()"
snippet ";([a,b,g,d,e,z,t,i,k,l,s,o,p,A,B,G,D,E,Z,T,I,K,L,S,O,P])" "Greek Letters 1" rAm
`!p snip.rv = keywords1[match.group(1)]`
endsnippet

######################################################################

context "math()"
snippet "'([t,p,f,m,n,e,T,P,F,M,N,E])" "Greek Letters 2" rAm
`!p snip.rv = keywords2[match.group(1)]`
endsnippet

######################################################################
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to describe "not working"? It's pretty unclear what's wrong from your question

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Done. I also realised that the problem was not with Python but with the `context` environment (or whatever it is called) but wasn't able to isolate the issue any further.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble maybe the problem is that I am using `vim.eval(...)` which only works for regular vim and I am using MacVim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have updated your plugins in the transition Linux to Mac. This also brings a [major update of Vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/releases/tag/v2.0), in which the syntax plugin has been included as part of Vimtex. Part of the syntax script changes are to simplify the math zones.

The exact issue you raise is discussed [here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1863#issuecomment-739915530), and [this comment](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1863#issuecomment-739915530) should provide the required change, repeated here for convenience. Change the top lines of your context script to this:

```
global !p
texMathZones = ['texMathZone' + x for x in ['', 'X', 'XX', 'Env', 'EnvStarred', 'Ensured']]
```

**Edit**: One can simplify the `global` part by using a built in function from vimtex:

```
global !p
def math():
    return vim.eval('vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone()') == '1'
endglobal
```

Comment: Is this a good fix? `context "vim.eval('vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone()')"` (instead of rolling out a custom `def math():` function.) I was just browsing vimtex code looking for such a function...

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Should have figured out to check for updates on Plugins.

Comment: @filbranden Yes, that looks like a good idea. I assume the returned value of `vim.eval` is still an integer. The function returns 1 for True and 0 for False, which should be compatible with Python. It will also handle the `texMathText` part. So, it seems the entire snippet code can be significantly simplified.

Comment: @GillesCastel I'm curious: Is it necessary to add `== '1'`? Did you check it? I expected the `vim.eval(...)` to return a number, as written above, in which case this should not be necessary...

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Without `== '1'`, the function always returns `True`. I also expected it to return a number but apparently it returns a string.

Comment: Ok; thanks for checking and commenting!